# Shibboleth IDp 3 NameID Generation

Tags: saml, shibboleth

I need to use a custom NameID format for one client that is using my IDP.

I can edit saml-nameid.xml to use an attribute in NameID and this works fine however it affects everyone that is using format urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient.

I know it is possible to have 2 NameID Generators associated with the format but it seems to just pick the first one as registered in saml-nameid.xml

How do I go about choosing between them based on which SP is calling my IDP.

Note I am using IDP version 3